# Getting format-table to work correctly with multiple sources

Tags: powershell, tabular

I want to check for specific services for a few specific servers and want the output to show on the same formatted table. I've only been able to create multiple tables, or to show only the last table formatted the way I want to. My intention is to show all on the same table.

```
Get-Service "ServiceA", "ServiceB", "ServiceC" -ComputerName SERVER1   
Get-Service "ServiceD", "ServiceE", "ServiceF" -ComputerName SERVER2 |
    Format-Table -Property MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName -Auto
```

How do I include SERVER1 and SERVER2 on the same formatted table? The example above will only show me formatted table for the SERVER2?

Other way I've tried was to

```
Get-Service "ServiceA", "ServiceB", "ServiceC" -ComputerName SERVER1 |
    Format-Table -Property MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName -Auto
Get-Service "ServiceD", "ServiceE", "ServiceF" -ComputerName SERVER2 |
    Format-Table -Property MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName -Auto
```

but that way there's two different tables created, and not all the info in only one like i would like to.

I need to check differente services on six different servers, but with just two I think is enough to exemplify my difficulties on this script.

Comment: (Get-Service "ServiceA", "ServiceB", "ServiceC" -computername SERVER1 ) + (Get-Service"ServiceD", "ServiceE", "ServiceF" -computername SERVER2) | ft  would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them both to appear in one table, you need to send *all* of the results over to `Format-Table` at the same time.  If you call `Format-Table` twice, you're going to get two separate tables.

Fortunately, PowerShell makes it really easy to store the results of a command in a variable, and then use that later.

What you need to do is make a variable to hold the results, and then store all of your `Get-Service` commands inside of it, like so:

```
#take the output and store it in $services
$services = get-service bits,winrm -computername ServerA
#add the output of the next to $services as well
$services += get-service AdobeARMservice,ALG -computername ServerB

#finally, make one big table to display it all
$services |Format-Table -Property MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName -auto

MachineName  Status Name            DisplayName                              
-----------  ------ ----            -----------                              
ServerA     Running bits            Background Intelligent Transfer Service  
ServerA     Running winrm           Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)
ServerB     Running AdobeARMservice Adobe Acrobat Update Service             
ServerB     Stopped ALG             Application Layer Gateway Service
```

Before you go too far down this rabbit hole, keep in mind that Format-Table is ONLY meant for viewing stuff in the console.  You can't take a table made with `FT` and then send export it as a .csv, for instance.  If you're OK with just viewing it in the console though, this should work.

Comment: Shouldn't `$s` be `$services`?

Comment: Yes, you're right!  Forgot to change that back for posting here.

Comment: using your example, can i color code the output? like red for stopped, green for running? if so, how? sorry if it's a pretty noob question, but i'm really taking baby steps over here.

Comment: Not natively, but here is a nice function you can add to your script to colorize the table! https://www.bgreco.net/powershell/format-color/

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
# create array
$services = @()

# add items to array
$services += Get-Service spooler
$services += Get-Service wsearch

# format array
$services | Format-Table -Property MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName -AutoSize
```

Or like this:

```
# create list
$services = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

# add items to list
$services.Add($(Get-Service spooler)) | Out-Null
$services.Add($(Get-Service wsearch)) | Out-Null

# display list
$services | Format-Table -Property MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName -AutoSize
```

Comment: I've done it with your first example, it worked as expected :)
Can i ask you another question? How can i color the output, red for stopped, green for running,  using the same first example you gave?

Comment: The PS console is not really meant to be used this way. Instead, I advise you to export results to Excel or HTML, where you can pretty-format things.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of populating an array or ArrayList, you can simply use a sub-expression to collate both outputs to a single Format-Table:

```
$(
  get-service "ServiceA", "ServiceB", "ServiceC" -computername SERVER1
  get-service "ServiceD", "ServiceE", "ServiceF" -computername SERVER2
) | Format-Table -Property MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName -auto
```

Answer (score 2):

Your examples don't produce the desired results, because for the first example only the output of the second `Get-Service` goes into `Format-Table`, and for the second example two separate tables are created.

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service) of the `Get-Service` cmdlet you'll notice that both the `-Name` and the `-ComputerName` take a string array as input, so if you want to check the same services on all computers you can simply do something like this:

```
$servers  = 'SERVER1', 'SERVER2'
$services = 'ServiceA', 'ServiceB', 'ServiceC'

Get-Service $services -ComputerName $servers |
    Format-Table -Property MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName -AutoSize
```

If you want to check different services on each server I'd map the services to the servers with a hashtable

```
$services = @{
    'SERVER1' = 'ServiceA', 'ServiceB', 'ServiceC'
    'SERVER2' = 'ServiceD', 'ServiceE', 'ServiceF'
}
```

and run `Get-Service` in a `ForEach-Object` loop, like this:

```
$services.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Service $services[$_] -ComputerName $_
} | Format-Table -Property MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName -AutoSize
```

or like this:

```
$services.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Service $_.Value -ComputerName $_.Name
} | Format-Table -Property MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName -AutoSize
```